# How to programatically determine if a gstreamer Element is a Bin?

Tags: c, gstreamer

I can see that methods exist for iterating over the GstElement's within a bin... but for any given GstElement is there are way to programatically determine if it is in fact a bin?

Comment: Since `GstBin` extends `GstElement`, it'd just be a quick type check (which the answer below got to before me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `GstElement`s are derived from the GLib `GObject` type, so the GLib `G_OBJECT_TYPE()` macro can be used to check the type:

```
if (G_OBJECT_TYPE(element) == GST_TYPE_BIN) ...
```

Even simpler is to use the convenience macros that are declared in [gstbin.h](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/gst/gstbin.h#L33):

```
if (GST_IS_BIN(element)) ...
```